# Failing to map drive for shared folder in WinPE (PXE/TFTP+DHCP server)

Tags: windows, pxe, tftp

I am failing to map a drive like this:

`net use z: \\server\sharedfolder`

it immediately returns an error 1231 telling me that the specified host can't be found - even though I have connected both pc's to my local router with a physical cable!

I have set up tftp32 to host a DHCP server ranging from 192.168.0.200 to 192.168.0.210

It's boot method is set to `boot\pxeboot.com` which loads into Windows PE. That is **not the problem**. I can easily get access to the network PXE-server I have set up. But when I enter the WinPE, I get the error as said above...

What can I do?

Comment: Once you're in WinPE do you get a network address? Are all the settings (Gateway, netmask etc.) proper?  Does it resolve when the IP address is used? Firewall on server? etc. etc.

Comment: Disabled the firewall on the DHCP server.... When selecting Network Boot at startup from the client computer, it immediately receives an IP from the DHCP IP-pool. And when entering WinPE afterwards, it executes `startnet.cmd`. All that batch-file does is to execute the `winpeinit`. But I get no messages after that.

Comment: Are you mapping the shared folder's server by name or IP address? Did you do any manual changes to the `Unattend.xml`?

Comment: Have tried both name and IP address. No idea what that file you refer to is. All I want is network access through WinPE to my other PC, so I can install windows.

Comment: When winpeinit runs it uses the Unattend.xml for settings like networking, etc.